# The argument type 'Future<void> Function(FirebaseUser)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(User)'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error while trying to connect my flutter app with Firebase and I don't understand why it's coming.

> The argument type 'Future<void> Function(FirebaseUser)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(User)'

The error is coming on this line with `_onStateChanged`. the full line is `_auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(_onStateChanged);`

Here is my auth.dart code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sokoni/src/helpers/user.dart';
import 'package:sokoni/src/models/user.dart';

enum Status {Uninitialized, Unauthenticated, Authenticating, Authenticated}

class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  // we're using the methods of the ChangeNotifier class in the AuthProvider class
  FirebaseAuth _auth;
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  FirebaseUser _user;
  Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;// initial status
  UserServices _userServices = UserServices();
  UserModel _userModel;

  //getters => we can access the values of a class but we cannot modify the values

  Status get status => _status;
  UserModel get userModel => _userModel;

  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  FirebaseUser get user => _user;

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  final FormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController name = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();




 AuthProvider.initialize(): _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance{
    //this listens to the user authentication state the we will do something about once a change is caught
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(_onStateChanged);
 }

  Future<bool> signIn() async{
    try{
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.text, password: password.text);
      return true;
    }catch(e){

      return _onError(e.toString());
    }

  }
  Future signOut(){
    _auth.signOut();
    _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
    return Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  }

  Future<bool> signUp() async{
   try{
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
    notifyListeners();
    await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.text, password: password.text).then((user) {
      Map<String, dynamic> values = {
        "name": name.text,
        "email": email.text,
        "id": user.user.uid,

      };
      _userServices.createUser(values);
    });

    return true;

   }catch(e){
     return _onError(e.toString());
    
   }
   
  }
   
       // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    Future<void> _onStateChanged(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) async{
     if(firebaseUser == null){
       _status =  Status.Uninitialized;
     }else {
       _user = firebaseUser;
       _status = Status.Authenticated;
       _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(firebaseUser.uid);
     }

     notifyListeners();
    }


    // my gen methods
    bool _onError(String error){
     _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
     notifyListeners();
     print("We got an error: $error");
     return false;
   }

   void cleanControllers (){
     email.text = " ";
     password.text = " ";
     name.text = " ";
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is this:

```
_auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((User user) async{
    await _onStateChanged(user);
     }
);
```

as the other answer suggests, change `FirebaseUser` to `User`

Answer (score 1):

`FirebaseUser` is now deprecated in the Firebase library and replaced with `User`,
you should change your method

```
Future<void> _onStateChanged(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) async{
     if(firebaseUser == null){
       _status =  Status.Uninitialized;
     }else {
       _user = firebaseUser;
       _status = Status.Authenticated;
       _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(firebaseUser.uid);
     }

     notifyListeners();
    }
```

to

```
Future<void> _onStateChanged(User user) async{
     if(user== null){
       _status =  Status.Uninitialized;
     }else {
       _user = user;
       _status = Status.Authenticated;
       _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(user.uid);
     }

     notifyListeners();
    }
```

you can check there [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#user-management) for new features